# Qualtrics javascript code only works when "viewing block", not when launching survey

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

I have created table with multiple input cells on one screen in a Qualtrics survey. The input cells were manually created using html, not standard input boxes used by Qualtrics due to the need for how the input boxes appeared.

I have been trying to use javascript and jquery to set embedded data based on what users input into the cells. I have been able to set embedded data to record when the users click on the cell again after writing something in it, but I would like to have the data embedded after they have finished writing in all the input cells and then click the next button.

I used the following code for the "on click" embedding:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function ()
{
this.questionclick = function(event,element){
var c = document.getElementById("cash").value;
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("chours", c);
}
});
```

And the following code for embedding the data when clicking the next button:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function ()
{
jq("form").submit(function(event,element){
var c = document.getElementById("cash").value;
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("chours", c);
}
)});
```

I have tried using this.clickNextbutton as well, which does not work. My problem is that I can get the data to embed when I am previewing/looking just at the individual question block in qualtrics, but it will not work once I have launched the survey and try to run it for real.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that qualtrics is first processing the next button before it attempts to process your JavaScript, at least when you try to run the real survey as opposed to just the preview.

One way around this, which might not be the most elegant, would be to create another button called "Submit" or something like this in HTML and to hide the next button. Now you can set the JavaScript for your "Submit"-button to save the answers as you have done before and then set a command to continue to the next slide as the last line in the same JavaScript.

You will need to use:

```
.hideNextButton();
```

and

```
.clickNextButton();
```

Hope this helps,
Felix